# Polymer svg - use xlink:href not working in Chrome 35

Tags: polymer

Using Polymer.js, I'm trying to use:

```
<template>
 <svg>
  <use xlink:href="file.svg#my-id"/>
 </svg>
</template>
```

and chrome will not load svg file when this code is inside polymer template tag.  Same code works fine outside template tag.  Firefox renders fine inside and outside polymer tag so it's only chrome and potentially only chrome 35.

Complete Example http://jsbin.com/dukiv/2/edit

I've searched internet for reported issues and found some issues reported against dart but nothing for Polymer.js. If this is a known issue, is there a workaround or issue I can track against?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in Chrome 35 when native ShadowDOM was enabled: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=356891.

It is fixed in Chrome 36

Comment: Thanks for replying.  So I guess there's no workaround other than waiting for chrome 35 to fade off the internet.

Comment: Since Chrome is auto-updating, there shouldn't be too many stragglers once 36 is out in a few weeks.